# Digital Ocean with Dokku for Rails 4 and Nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, digital-ocean

I recently switch from using Heroku to DigitalOcean. I have to say that nothing beats the pleasure of using Heroku, unless the concern is about server location, and price.

Deploying my existing Rails app from Heroku to Digital Ocean with Dokku is pretty smooth, but I wonder if Nginx is being used to serve the Rails app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. I stop Nginx, and the server is still serving the app.